Why Cucumber/Maven/Junit Eclipse project frequently gets "orange" lines in .feature file and Maven-Update fixes it?
I am still kind of new to working with Cucumber/Maven/Junit in Eclipse, but I've noticed that once in a while (quite frequently) some of the lines in a .feature file suddenly has some "orange" lines.
I was working with one of the more experienced devs and he said "just do Maven->Update Project" and sure enough that cleaned up the problem and now all the step lines have the green circle.
I ran into this again tonight and also noticed that in the Eclipse console warnings there were a bunch of "glue missing" warnings.
So now, I am curious: (a) what causes those "orange" lines to "suddenly" appear like that and (b) is there a way to avoid them appearing like that randomly?  Or is it just the way that things work with Cucumber/Maven/Junit projects in Eclipse?
Thanks,
Jim
P.S.  I don't have an example to take screenshots right now but if I encounter one I will add to this question.
EDIT 1:  I'm not sure what to make of it, but the following is the Eclipse console output (a) when the error occurs after I changed the .feature file, then (b) after I did the Maven ==> Update project:
.log when error occurred after changed the .feature file (got orange lines):

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Cucumber gherkins builder' on project 'CucumberProject'.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes\.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.


AFTER did Maven==>Update Project:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2024-07-10 09:01:59.930
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2024-07-10 09:01:59.940
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

EDIT 2: the .metadata/.log file contents:

Blockquote

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2024-07-10 08:56:39.035
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:135)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
... 23 more
!SUBENTRY 1 cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration 4 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.046
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(/CucumberProject/target/classes/.cucumber/cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp)[368]: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2024-07-10 08:56:39.046
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 1 cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration 4 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.046
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(/CucumberProject/target/classes/.cucumber/cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp)[368]: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2024-07-10 08:56:39.046
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.593
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.610
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 cucumber.eclipse.editor 4 75 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Cucumber gherkins builder' on project 'CucumberProject'.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:135)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
... 23 more
!SUBENTRY 2 cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration 4 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(/CucumberProject/target/classes/.cucumber/cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp)[368]: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 1 cucumber.eclipse.steps.integration 4 0 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException(/CucumberProject/target/classes/.cucumber/cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp)[368]: java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:290)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.load(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:78)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.StepDefinitionsStorage.getOrCreate(StepDefinitionsStorage.java:36)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:47)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.steps.UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.getStepDefinitions(UniversalStepDefinitionsProvider.java:43)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:155)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.incrementalBuild(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:129)
at cucumber.eclipse.editor.builder.CucumberGherkinBuilder.build(CucumberGherkinBuilder.java:101)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 368 2024-07-10 08:56:39.920
!MESSAGE File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: File not found: E:\Eclipse-Cucumber-workspace\CucumberProject\target\classes.cucumber\cucumber.stepDefinitions.tmp.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.provideStackTrace(ResourceException.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException.(ResourceException.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:882)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:299)
.
.

Just a guess. Eclipse keeps a model of your project in memory. This model is used by the Eclipse plugin that does the highlighting. I guess that as you make changes this plugin breaks. When you reimport the project, Eclipse throws everything aways, rebuilds the model and restarts the plugin. Maybe check the error log in Eclipse to see if it has anything interesting in it.

M.P. Korstanje - I've added console logging from when the problem occurs.
